# IIS IP Address and Domain Restrictions or Dynamic IP Address Restrictions?

Tags: iis, blacklist, iis-10

I would like to implement dynamic ip address based restrictions in my IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019, and find a way (even it involves some programming/scripting/automation) to integrate it with blacklists provided by Project Honeypot.

I am not sure which one (if any) should I use. I do not want to blacklist domain names, because of DNS query performance cost, just IPs

Comment: Examples can be found in https://www.sans.org/blog/windows-firewall-script-to-block-ip-addresses-and-country-network-ranges/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `IP Address and Domain Restrictions` not the dynamic restrictions. You just need to add the addresses or networks to you list of blocked entries for a site or the whole server.

You can have a PowerShell script which downloads a blacklist from somewhere and they translates the content of that list into the IIS settings.

`Dynamic Restriction` doesn't use a particular address, but blocks any address based on requests coming from that address.